# How to fix this error read property 'cycle' of undefined for Bootsrap Carousel Slider?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, console

I have tested the bootsrap carousel slider on a test page on one of my site

This is the code for the slider to slide automatically :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 300
})
</script>
```

Slider Code :

```
<div id="carousel-coupons" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-coupons" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-coupons" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-coupons" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<div class="carousel-item  active">
     <a href="#">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="/1.jpg" alt="Firstslide"></a>
    </div> 

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="/2.jpg" alt="Second slide"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="/3.jpg" alt="Third slide"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-coupons" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>

  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-coupons" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is th Error Code in console :

```
core.jquery.js?ver=4.5.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cycle' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `bootstrap.min.js` well referenced?

Comment: yes , i have the same piece of code working on other place , but not on wordpress platform ...